# SHA1 HMAC a byte array with Arduino

Tags: arduino, hmacsha1

How can I HMAC a byte array on an Arduino?  I've found [this library](https://github.com/Cathedrow/Cryptosuite) for SHA1 HMACs, but it appears to be used only for strings.

I've passed it bytes in a null-terminated byte array.  This does give me the correct result.   But doesn't work so well for byte arrays that contain zeros!

```
uint8_t hmacKey1[]={   0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x21, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef };
uint8_t time[]={   0xb2, 0x00 };

Sha1.initHmac(hmacKey1, 10);
Sha1.print((char*)time);
```

Either I need to find another another library ([crypto-arduino-library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-arduino-library/) looks promising, but doesn't include any examples for what I'm doing), or hack up the Cathedrow library to do what I'm after.

Does anyone know of another way?

Comment: IIRC the base class `Print` provides such methods. Else just use a loop and `Print::write`

Comment: @leppie yes, the loop did the trick for me thx

Comment: Glad I could help :) Havent coded for Arduino in ages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding my own method appears to have done the trick:

```
void Sha1Class::writebytes(const uint8_t* data, int length) {
 for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
 {
   write(data[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change sha1.cpp you can just loop and print each single byte, the trick is to use `Sha1.print((char) basestring[i]);`, like so:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <sha1.h>

char key[] = "testKey";
uint8_t basestring[] = { 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67 }; // testing

void printHash(uint8_t* hash) {  
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]>>4]);
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]&0xf]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.print("Input:              ");
  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(basestring); i++) {
    Serial.print((char) basestring[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Key:                ");
  Serial.println(key);

  Serial.print("Hmac-sha1 (hex):    ");
  Sha1.initHmac((uint8_t*)key, strlen(key));

  for (int i=0; i<sizeof(basestring); i++) {
    Sha1.print((char) basestring[i]);
  }

  uint8_t *hash;
  hash = Sha1.resultHmac();
  printHash(hash);

}

void loop() { }
```

**Output**

```
Input:              testing
Key:                testKey
Hmac-sha1 (hex):    60d41271d43b875b791e2d54c34bf3f018a29763
```